# Bug in Microsoft Word with Find and Replace when searching text containing a hyperlink?

Tags: microsoft-word, find-and-replace, microsoft-word-2013, hyperlink

I was trying to replace a text with a email address in the middle of it in a Word document. If I only use the Find command, then it works fine, and Microsoft Word finds the text I wanted to replace.

[image]

The problem comes when I actually try to do the replacement, then mysteriously Word tells me that the text could not be found (the same text and same document) so unfortunately no replacements were made.

[image]

It is because the email address is treated as a hyperlink. If I remove the hyperlink, it works just fine, but this is not a solution for me because I am trying to make a program for the use of many people and by default the option to make automatically the email address a hyperlink is activated in Word.

Is there any workaround to solve this? I am considering other options but if this could be done with the replace command of Word would be much easier for me.

For the info: I tested this in a Microsoft Office 2003 and Microsoft Office 2013. It does not work either, so it is not a version related problem but something general to all versions of Microsoft Word.

Comment: Did you not find a work around? The only alternative I can think kids of is to write a VBa for this...

Comment: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-word/findreplace-in-hyperlinks/0f78b0a1-d7d0-48c5-865a-a240d16aef8c

Comment: Is there any way to do your specific search and replace task without searching for a mixture of hyperlinks and plain text? From my testing, the issue does not exist if you try to replace the hyperlink by itself.

Comment: I think @sunk818's comment in combination with [MS Word's regex](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-and-replace-text-by-using-regular-expressions-Advanced-eeaa03b0-e9f3-4921-b1e8-85b0ad1c427f) gives an answer.

Comment: The error prompt does not appear, but if you do a search and replace... The visual text of the email changes, but the properties still remain the old email. Hover over the link after you do a successful search and replace and you should still see the old email.

Comment: This question kept bugging me, so I tried with [MS Word's regex patterns](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-and-replace-text-by-using-regular-expressions-Advanced-eeaa03b0-e9f3-4921-b1e8-85b0ad1c427f#bm8) but the problem is you want to search for the beginning/end of a field (with ^d) but [that does not work in combination with wildcards](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714947/how-to-do-search-and-replace-involving-fields-in-microsoft-word). Long story short: MS Word can't do this out-of-the-box. As said, VBA is a solution, but I'm not sure if you want to go in that direction.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments, I am already using vba (well more specifically VB.NET with the API of word) and I have several other issues (with tables as well). But this one is driving me crazy. If you try the same with vba with the instruction Find.Execute, it does not work. Is there any other way to find a text that include a email address within using vba? I will post it more detailed in StackOverflow to see if someone could help me. At the beggining I used to read the whole text of the document and do it myself, but this is very slow for big documents so no luck.

Comment: @Dave Do you know any way to do this with VBa?

Answer (score 2):

You could use VBA...

1) Remove all hyperlinks (leaving text).

```vb
Sub RemoveHyperlinks()
     With ThisDocument
         While .Hyperlinks.Count > 0
            .Hyperlinks(1).Delete
         Wend
     End With
End Sub
```

2) Do your search and replace...

3) Recreate all hyperlinks (if user has the auto-hyperlink option in Word enabled):

```vb
Sub ReformatDocument()
     Selection.WholeStory
     Selection.Document.Kind = wdDocumentNotSpecified
     Selection.Range.AutoFormat
End Sub
```

Additionally, if you want to enable or disable the actual autocorrect option for automatic hyperlinks you can use "Application.Options.AutoFormatAsYouTypeReplaceHyperlinks":

i.e.: `Application.Options.AutoFormatAsYouTypeReplaceHyperlinks = False`

Comment: Although helpful, I think this is dangerous code (so sorry, but -1), because I relies on the assumption that all hyperlinks are auto-hyperlink links. Any manually edited or added hyperlink will just disappear. This will happen sometimes, because Word allows "hyperlinks" [to other files or sections in a document as well as www hyperlinks](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/word-help/field-codes-hyperlink-field-HP005189544.aspx). A solution might be to replace existing hyperlinks with some code and find/replace or reparse the text, but that will require a bit more (complex) VBA.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is helpful. For the moment, until I find another solution, I am deleting all the hyperlinks in the document asking permission to the user if he wants to use my program. Bun unfortunately as @agtoever says I can't know if the email addresses where links or not (even with the AutoFormat option enable) because you can manually erase hyperlinks. agtoever, I am not again reparsing but I discarded that idea because with big documents is slow and my code runs in a timer...

Comment: @agtoever you are correct, it's a sledgehammer approach that wasn't intended to be a full solution for the OP and everyone else who may read it. ;)  "A solution might be to replace existing hyperlinks with some code and find/replace or reparse the text, but that will require a bit more (complex) VBA" Please feel free to offer an answer to help the OP.